# Linux - get a report of what programs a command line perl script calls and the files it produces and uses

Tags: linux, python, perl, monitoring

I have a Perl script that calls about 10 other perl scripts some of which call Python scripts.  Each of those produce files which the other programs read.  It's pretty complex.

What I would like to do is run it, and have Linux report which programs called which programs, and which files each program read in, and produced?

Is some kind of trace like that possible in Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
strace -fF -o /tmp/debugfile your_script.pl
```

And then

```
grep open /tmp/debugfile
```

If that does not catch everything, audit subsystem in Linux kernel could help you.

Comment: Cool beans.  I used quanta's syntax below.  It seems to be working.  Do you know of any tools to parse the output into something more readable?

Answer (score 4):

```
$ strace -f -e trace=process,open -o /tmp/script.strace script.pl
```